# I'm getting this error when ran ng e2e: Could not find update-config.json

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, e2e-testing

Currently I have Protractor v.5.4.2, Node.js v.10.15.39

> [09:21:29] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>   [09:21:29] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
>   [09:21:29] E/direct - Error code: 135
>   [09:21:29] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.driver-manager update' to download binaries.                                    anager update' to download binaries.
>   [09:21:29] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-mes\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:63:31)

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix it? What happened?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver  I installed
`npm install protractor`

Updated web driver manager
`webdriver-manager update`

Ran this command from my root
`node node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager update`
I started up a server with:
`webdriver-manager start`

ran e2e tests on different browsers
ng e2e

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem.

1. **Option 1: In terminal, you can try**

`project-dir$ webdriver-manager update`

or

```
project-dir$ ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```

or

```
project-dir$ ./node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```

or

```
project-dir$ ./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update
```

2. **Option 2: You can update Gruntfile.js (jenskin,...)**

Following [grunt-protractor-runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-runner) you can see **options.webdriverManagerUpdate**.
This is option which auto update webdriver-manager in **/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner**. If you use this way, you don't have to use `project-dir$ ./node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`

**Gruntfile.js**
`protractor: { options: { configFile: "test/e2e/protractor-conf.js", noColor: false, webdriverManagerUpdate:true, args: {} }, e2e: { options: { // Stops Grunt process if a test fails keepAlive: false, } } },`