# Error for e2e : Process exited with error code 135

Tags: angular, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am new in angular and I trying to run e2e but I got the below error on windows OS and not getting what is this.

````
[09:50:58] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:50:58] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[09:50:58] E/direct - Error code: 135
[09:50:58] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.enter code here
[09:50:58] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
 E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135```
````

Comment: your error log itself says to run 'webdriver-manager update' , did you try this?

Comment: Yes I tried but still the same error.

Comment: Solution is in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333886/im-getting-this-error-when-ran-ng-e2e-could-not-find-update-config-json/62380248#62380248). Please vote if it's helpful for you!